# React-Native-FS Compiling Error

Tags: android

I tried installing `react-native-fs` on my Android project but while compiling it returnded an error from the `MainActivity.java`:

```
Error: cannot find symbol
      setContentView(mReactRootView);
                     ^
  symbol:   variable mReactRootView
  location: class MainActivity
```

It was a piece of code I had to add manually in the file but I don't know how to fix it. The full guide I followed for the installation is on

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs/v/1.2.0

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using RN +0.40, follow step below instead docs step "register module (in MainActivity.java)" go in MainApplication.java

```
// MainApplication.java
import com.syarul.rnlocation.RNFSPackage; // <--- import
...
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new MainReactPackage(),
      new RNFSPackage() // <-- Register package here or packages.add(new RNFSPackage());
  );
}
```